# List of common first names for text analysis in R?

Tags: r, nlp, tidytext

In analysing text, it can be useful to identify names of people in text data.

Objects prepackaged in [`tidytext`](https://www.tidytextmining.com/tidytext.html) include:

- English negators, modals, and adverbs (`nma_words`)
- Parts of Speech (`parts_of_speech`)
- Sentiments (`sentiments`), and
- Stop Words (see: `?stop_words`)

Is there a similar object in R (or in accessible format elsewhere) containing a canonical list of names?

For reference, here are the existing `data.frame`s that are supplied with `tidytext`

```
nma_words
# # A tibble: 44 x 2
# word      modifier
# <chr>     <chr>   
#   1 cannot    negator 
# 2 could not negator 
# 3 did not   negator 
# 4 does not  negator 
# 5 had no    negator 
# 6 have no   negator 
# 7 may not   negator 
# 8 never     negator 
# 9 no        negator 
# 10 not       negator 
# # … with 34 more rows


parts_of_speech
# # A tibble: 208,259 x 2
#    word    pos      
#    <chr>   <chr>    
#  1 3-d     Adjective
#  2 3-d     Noun     
#  3 4-f     Noun     
#  4 4-h'er  Noun     
#  5 4-h     Adjective
#  6 a'      Adjective
#  7 a-1     Noun     
#  8 a-axis  Noun     
#  9 a-bomb  Noun     
# 10 a-frame Noun     
# # … with 208,249 more rows


sentiments
# # A tibble: 6,786 x 2
#    word        sentiment
#    <chr>       <chr>    
#  1 2-faces     negative 
#  2 abnormal    negative 
#  3 abolish     negative 
#  4 abominable  negative 
#  5 abominably  negative 
#  6 abominate   negative 
#  7 abomination negative 
#  8 abort       negative 
#  9 aborted     negative 
# 10 aborts      negative 
# # … with 6,776 more rows


stop_words
# # A tibble: 1,149 x 2
#    word        lexicon
#    <chr>       <chr>  
#  1 a           SMART  
#  2 a's         SMART  
#  3 able        SMART  
#  4 about       SMART  
#  5 above       SMART  
#  6 according   SMART  
#  7 accordingly SMART  
#  8 across      SMART  
#  9 actually    SMART  
# 10 after       SMART  
# # … with 1,139 more rows
```

Comment: There are tens of millions of unique names in the world, and people create new ones every day. Any such list would be massive, incomplete, frequently out-of-date and never canonical.

Comment: @AllanCameron yep it would be, it would be up to user beware like the other lists

Comment: You might start with the `babynames` package although this is built solely from US data.

Comment: Check the [lexicon package](https://github.com/trinker/lexicon). It contains lists of common names, first names, last names and a whole bunch muore

Comment: `library(lexicon); lexicon::freq_first_names` has ~5500 names from the 1990 US census. `library(genderdata); ssa_national` comes from the Social Security Administration through time from 1880 through 2012, showing some ~9500 female and similar number of male names in total.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Datasets like these are super complicated and must be used with care. One source of such data is the [genderdata](https://docs.ropensci.org/genderdata/) package which includes several name datasets, including several from the US Social Security Administration.

```r
library(genderdata)

head(ssa_national)
#>    name year female male
#> 1 aaban 2007      0    5
#> 2 aaban 2009      0    6
#> 3 aaban 2010      0    9
#> 4 aaban 2011      0   11
#> 5 aaban 2012      0   11
#> 6 aabha 2011      7    0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>